# _env oerror while access administrator area in joomla 1.5 version websites we have developed

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

We're getting the following error while trying to access the admin panel on our Joomla 1.5 site:

```
Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script.
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please firstly ensure that you are running the latest version of the Joomla 1.5 series which is 1.5.26

If this does not solve the issue, it could be due to the fact that you're using a security plugin for you admin panel. If you need to access the admin panel by typing in a key after the URL like so AND it's a number:

***www.mysite.com/administrator?12345***

Then change the key so that it doesn't use numbers

This error is actually produced by Joomla and not PHP, so as mentioned before, ensure you running the latest version. I would also recommend that you upgrade to Joomla 2.5 or 3.x as 1.5 has some pretty big security flaws.

Comment: Thanks for the details. We are running this website from 2009 onwards. and recently this issue occurred. We have three websites in same server and all these websites are having same issue.